# Potential Altitude Inaccuracies Throwing Total Altitude Gain

Tags: flutter, go, geolocation

I am using Location Package in flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/location) and getting the users altitude every second.  It seems to be working but when I calculate the elevation gain then I am getting a much higher number than I would expect.

My logic is quite simple:

I loop through all the altitudes in order that were captured and if the current altitude was a number that is larger than the previous altitude then I add it to the totalAltitude gain.   Unfortunately I am using other (trusted) apps as well and their numbers are much lower than mine.  My altitude gain is 3-4 x what theirs is showing.

Is this due to inaccuracies in my altitude?   Should I be using a different formula?

Below is some code (golang) that I am using to calculate the total altitude:

```
    //Get the starting altitude
placeholderValue := float32(-99999.9999)
previousAltitude := placeholderValue
totalAltitude := 0.0
for _, value := range capturedDataEvents {
    if value != nil && value.AltitudeMeters != nil {
        //Set the starter value if the previous altidude has a placeholder
        if previousAltitude == placeholderValue {
            previousAltitude = *value.AltitudeMeters
        }

        //Check whether difference
        difference := *value.AltitudeMeters - previousAltitude
        if difference > 0 {
            totalAltitude += float64(difference)
        }
        previousAltitude = *value.AltitudeMeters
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a method similar to dead-reckoning, which suffers from an accumulation of errors. Instead of adding differences, keep a max altitude.

Comment: Thank you,  Just so I am sure that I understand.   You suggest keeping a max and a minimum and then that would be my elevation gain?   The challenge that I have is that someone could climb many hills on the way to the max and I want to use that data as well.  For example, they could climb the same 500 meter climb 3 times and I would want the elevation gained to be 1500 meters and not just 500.

Comment: You need a more complicated analysis of the time series, then. You need to identify maxima and minima, and look at the differences between those in time.

Comment: Thanks.   Yeah, I can see that helping.  You are 100% correct with the accumulation of errors.  I guess that I could break my larger time series into smaller pieces, identify the maxima and minima of each (and get the elevation gain) and then add all of those into a total elevation gain.

Comment: Making it more realistic, let's imagine altitude is up to 15 feet inaccurate on each measurement.  Do you really want "100, 115, 100, 115, 100, 115" (which could be the series of a measurement even when standing still) to show a 45 foot climb?

Comment: Put another way, look at "the length of a coastline", a typical introduction to fractals.  The length is completely different depending on whether you use miles, yards, feet, or inches to measure.  Read up on fractal measurements for more details (heh).